# How long could a satellite orbit a comet without any control?

Tags: orbit, rosetta, comet

As a follow up of the comments here: [Why was the Rosetta probe programmed to "auto shutoff" at the moment of hitting the surface?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18482/why-was-the-rosetta-probe-programmed-to-auto-shutoff-at-the-moment-of-hitting/18503?noredirect=1#comment48373_18503)

I'm fairly convince that a satellite cannot maintain an orbit above a comet, being quickly ousted or crashing by

1. The comet pressure
2. The effect of other bodies perturbing the orbit

Not helping is the very irregular gravity field of the comet.

Answer (score 4):

Comet 67P/Churyumov–Gerasimenko has a mass of about 9.982 gigatonnes, a semimajor axis of 3.4630 AU, and an eccentricity of 0.64102. If it was a point mass, it's Hill sphere would be about [221 km](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3.4630%20AU)*(1-0.64102)*((9.982e12%20kg)%2F(3*(solar%20mass)))%5E(1%2F3)). The Hill sphere is an approximation regarding the volume within which orbits are stable. A more reasonable limit is 1/3 to 1/2 the Hill sphere radius, or 74 to 110 km. I'll use 100 km as a nice round number.

67P is anything but a point mass. The highly non-spherical nature of its gravitational field will definitely be felt at ~100 km from the center of mass. This would make the issues with [lunar mascons](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2006/06nov_loworbit) tiny in comparison.

Plus it's a comet. It emits gases and sometimes boulders when it is close to perihelion. The odds of not being plumed or hit while the comet is near perihelion are astronomically low. Even if a body orbiting the comet isn't plumed or hit by a boulder, the non-gravitational forces on the comet itself will almost certainly be enough to make any orbit about the comet unstable.